# Query or SQL to return multiple columns with one unique column

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am working is MS Access 2007 with a query that contains the following columns:
PATIENT_NUMBER
DATE_OF_VISIT
BMI

The query contains multiple DATE_OF_VISITS (with associated BMI) for each PATIENT_NUMBER. I have been trying to use SQL to give me an unduplicated list of all patients with the most recent date of visit and the BMI at that visit.

So far I can get a list of the most recent date of visit for each patient but when I try and get BMI as well I start getting multiple instances of patients (since their BMI fluctuates over time)

Comment: Since you have a query which returns most recent visit for each patient, use that as a subquery which you join back to the original table to retrieve the BMI for each of those visits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to include any queries that you've tried in the question.  I think you need something like this:

```
select t.PATIENT_NUMBER, t.DATE_OF_VISIT, t.BMI
from t inner join
     (select PATIENT_NUMBER, max(DATE_OF_VISIT) as maxdate
      from t
      group by PATIENT_NUMBER
     ) tmax
     on t.PATIENT_NUMBER = tmax.PATIENT_NUMBER and t.DATE_OF_VISIT = tmax.maxdate;
```

This assumes that there are not duplicate dates for the same patient.  If so, you will need some other method to disambiguate them.

Comment: I tried your suggested code and assumed that the "t" was a placeholder for the name of the base query. What I have was formatted as this:  SELECT [BBHS Year Two Multiple BMI].PATIENT_NUMBER, [BBHS Year Two Multiple BMI].DATE_OF_VISIT, [BBHS Year Two Multiple BMI].BMI
FROM [BBHS Year Two Multiple BMI]
JOIN (SELECT PATIENT_NUMBER, max(DATE_OF_VISIT) AS maxdate FROM [BBHS Year Two Multiple BMI]) tmax
ON [BBHS Year Two Multiple BMI].PATIENT_NUMBER = tmax.PATIENT_NUMBER AND [BBHS Year Two Multiple BMI].DATE_OF_VISIT = tmax.maxdate;               However I get the error "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Comment: Access will not let you use `JOIN` without specifying the type of join.  I think you want `INNER JOIN` here.

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working. Now I get the error "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "PATIENT_NUMBER' as part of an aggregate function."